# Query elements, which only belong to a set of classes

Tags: html, css

`document.querySelectorAll(".a, .b")` returns a `NodeList` of all HTML elements which belong to the classes a and b.

Likewise `document.getElementsByClassName("a b")` returns a `HTMLCollection` containing the same elements.

How can those results being narrowed to those elements, that exclusively belong to those classes: Omitting e.g. elements which belong to the classes a, b and c.

Comment: Will the order of `a` and `b` always be the same? You may be able to query based on the value of the `class` attribute if so.

Comment: I'm unsure exactly what you're asking. would it be possible to update your question with some sample HTML and the results you would expect?

Comment: BenM: practically the order will me the same. theoretically you cannot rely on that.

Comment: ".a, .b returns a NodeList of all HTML elements which belong to the classes a and b." It returns a NodeList of the elements that belong to either class, not necessarily both. You probably meant .a.b.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `:not` selector like so:

```js
var abOnly = document.querySelectorAll(".a:not(.c), .b:not(.c)");

console.log(Array.from(abOnly).map(el => el.innerText));
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="a b">ab</li>
  <li class="a b c">abc</li>
  <li class="a b">ab</li>
</ul>
```

You could also go with a half-query half-js approach:

```js
var hasAB = Array.from(
  document.querySelectorAll(".a, .b")
);

var noC = hasAB.filter(el => !el.classList.contains("c"));

console.log(noC.map(el => el.innerText));
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="a b">ab</li>
  <li class="a b c">abc</li>
  <li class="a b">ab</li>
</ul>
```

**Edit after comment: "A more general approach"**

Some examples of how to use a combination of `querySelectorAll` and `classList` to do advanced queries:

```js
var twoClassesAB = Array
  .from(document.querySelectorAll(".a.b"))
  .filter(el => el.classList.length === 2)
  .map(innerText)
  .join(" ");

var aOrBWithoutC = Array
  .from(document.querySelectorAll(".a, .b"))
  .filter(el => !el.classList.contains("c"))
  .map(innerText)
  .join(" ");
                                  



console.log("Only a and b, nothing else:", twoClassesAB)

console.log("At least one of a and b, explicitly not c:", aOrBWithoutC)

// Utils
function innerText(el) { return el.innerText; };
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="a b">ab</li>
  <li class="a b c">abc</li>
  <li class="a b">ab</li>
  <li class="a b d">abd</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: the c class was just an example, it needs to be more general

Comment: I've added an approach that shows how you can filter via an array filter as well. Of course, you can create your queries and filters using variable class names. Can you explain with more detail what you mean by "more general"?

Comment: I think checking the length selects only those elements which belong to class .a and .b and no other classes: `document.querySelectorAll(".a, .b").filter(el => el.classList.length == 2)`

Comment: @AntonHarald You would need to check for `length == 3`, since: `["a", "b", value: "a b"]`

Comment: @AntonHarald When you use the query `".a.b"` you can use `length === 2` because this query searches elements that have *both* classes. When you do `".a, .b"` it makes no sense, since this is an *or* query.

Comment: @BenM I don't think I understand your comment correctly, can you elaborate?

Comment: @user3297291 Please see the jsFiddle I have posted in response to your comment on my answer.